# Simple Captcha and make different colors

Tags: java, servlets, graphics, captcha, simplecaptcha

I've just watched the link as http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/ and it gives demo of some images showing that captcha can be designed as a colored one so it can be not only black and white one. But for some reason I couldn't find any tutorials of how control SimpleCaptcha colors :( If you know some snippets or tutorials share them please.

All useful comments are appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which part do you want to be in color? You can, for example, control the color of the text via a `WordRenderer`. Examples of how to use their `Captcha.Builder` can be found [on their website](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/custom_images.html). You can add things like the following to any of these examples:

```
List<java.awt.Color> textColors = Arrays.asList(
     Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED);
List<java.awt.Font> textFonts = Arrays.asList(
     new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40), 
     new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 40));

java.awt.Color backgroundColor = Color.ORANGE;

Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(200, 50)
    .addText(
        new DefaultTextProducer(), 
        new DefaultWordRenderer(textColors, textFonts))
    .addBackground(new FlatColorBackgroundProducer(backgroundColor))
    .build();
```

`DefaultWordRenderer` accepts a `List` of colors and fonts so that you can pick from several colors/fonts randomly per request. So, if you provide it with only one color and font, then you'll get those every time. If you provide it with five colors and one font, then you'll get the same font every time, but the color will be selected randomly from the five that you provided.

The example above uses `FlatColorBackgroundProducer`, but there are other options, including `GradiatedBackgroundProducer` and `SquigglesBackgroundProducer`.

Comment: I want to control text color and background color but I couldn't find any snippets showing how to programm new MyTextProducer(), new DefaultWordRenderer(colors, fonts) objects :(

Comment: For example, I'd like to make background blue and text dark-blue but I don't know how to modify Simple Captcha Objects for this :( Is it something like a Swing repainting or how?

Comment: And why are you using List of colors?

Comment: I updated the example to answer some of your questions. As for the question of how to plug this in to a real, running application ( I don't know how to modify Simple Captcha Objects for this), have you looked at their Example Applications? Would you post what you've got so far?

Comment: Thank you for more detailed answer :) Well, I couldn't find any working example except the black and white one :( That's why I asked to share some snippets to watch the conception...

Comment: It sounds like you have the info that you need now. Please accept the answer in case somebody else asks the same question later.

Answer (score 1):

Probably using Class ColoredEdgesWordRenderer. Take look at http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index.html